# Inequality with Absolute Value on both sides?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

My math teacher isn't the best. So can someone please explain how I can solve this problem?

$$|x+3| \ge |6x+9|$$

I tried doing it myself by splitting into two inequalities but my answer was very different.

Answer (score 3):

hint:

square both sides and solve for $x$

Comment: +1 for elegance

Comment: I'll try it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Condition 1**: For $x\geq-\frac{3}{2}$
$$\begin{align}x+3&\geq6x+9\\
-5x&\geq6\\
x&\leq-\frac{6}{5}\end{align}$$
Merge overlapping interval and we got
$$-\frac{3}{2}\leq x\leq-\frac{6}{5}$$

**Condition 2**: For $-3\leq x < -\frac{3}{2}$
$$\begin{align}x+3&\geq-6x-9\\
7x&\geq-12\\
x&\geq-\frac{12}{7}\end{align}$$
Merge overlaping interval and we got
$$-\frac{12}{7}\leq x \leq -\frac{3}{2}$$

**Condition 3**: For $x<-3$
$$\begin{align}-x-3&\geq-6x-9\\
5x&\geq-6\\
x&\geq-\frac{6}{5}\end{align}$$
Merge overlapping interval and we got
$$\varnothing$$

Merge all interval from those three conditions and we got
$$-\frac{12}{7} \leq x \leq -\frac{6}{5}$$

Comment: Did you mean condition (1) $x\color{red}\ge\frac32$ and condition (3) $x<\color{red}-3$ and forget a minus sign on the result of condition (2)?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes, thanks for your correction.

Comment: hmm I'll take some time to think about this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

We have:
 $$0\geq|6x+9|-|x+3|=\frac{(6x+9)^2-(x+3)^2}{|6x+9|+|x+3|}=\frac{35x^2+102x+72}{|6x+9|+|x+3|}=\frac{(7x+12)(5x+6)}{|6x+9|+|x+3|}$$ and since
$$|6x+9|+|x+3|>0,$$
we got the answer:
$$\left[-\frac{12}{7},-\frac{6}{5}\right].$$

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?

Comment: +1 for a different approach. However, is not it a go-around method to simply squaring?

Comment: @farruhota they are similar, but by my way we got an answer in one line, which I specially like.